# Python - Mocking the behavior of an object outside of a function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have 3 files:

main.py

```
from util import ResultGetter

result_getter = ResultGetter()
result = result_getter.get_result()

def function_a():
    return result
```

util.py

```
class ResultGetter:
    def get_result(self):
        return False
```

and test_main.py

import main
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

```
def test_function_a():
    def get_new_result():
        return True
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
    monkeypatch.setattr(main.result_getter, "get_result", get_new_result)
    result = main.function_a()
    assert(result == True)
```

I'm attempting to override the behavior of get_result with get_new result and make the assertion True. However it's still pulling in the False from util.py.

I am new to mocking in python, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that this block below is set outside the scope of the function :

```
result_getter = ResultGetter()
result = result_getter.get_result()
```

I changed the main.py to :

```
from util import ResultGetter

def function_a():
    return ResultGetter().get_result()
```

And it worked. The problem here is you can't access the value of the object outside the function with the `MonkeyPatch` or even with the `patch` function like :

```
 with patch("__main__.ResultGetter.get_result") as get_new_result:
     get_new_result.return_value= True
     result = function_a()
```

Since it's set up beforehands your test from the object `result_getter`.